# Django, reuse select_related/prefetch_related on reverse related manager?

Tags: django, django-models

I can see select_related decreases # of queries.

However, when I run the same query multiple times, I expect to see the first query gets reused but it's not in the following setup.

```
class Foo(models.Model):

    pass


class Bar(models.Model):

    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars')
    blog = models.ForeignKey('blg.blog')



foo = Foo.objects.create()
bar1 = Bar.objects.create(foo=foo)
bar2 = Bar.objects.create(foo=foo)

foo.bars.select_related('blog')
foo.bars.select_related('blog') # <= here, it runs the query again
```

How can I tell django to reuse the first DB query on the second run?

Answer (score 0):

`select_related` does not imply any caching, it just does a `JOIN` so that you do not need a new database query to fetch related objects of the returned objects.

```
for bar in foo.bars.all():
    bar.blog  # A query to fetch the blog object is made for each bar object in the loop.

for bar in foo.bars.select_related('blog'):
    bar.blog  # No query is made, the blog object has already been fetched.
```

If you do not want to make multiple database queries, just store the queryset into a variable and reuse that same queryset, for example:

```
bars = foo.bars.select_related('blog')

for bar in bars:  # The first loop executes the DB query and caches its result
    # Do something

for bar in bars:  # The second loop uses the cached results
    # Do something else
```

Comment: Nice answer, but converting the queryset into a list is pointless. First of all it takes up computing power and slows down your code, secondly it doesn't change anything executing wise. You can easily iterate over querysets and the query will be run before the first loop instead of being run for the listing.

Comment: @makaveli It does not slow down your code much if you intended to iterate over the queryset anyway, it just uses memory. It is necessary if you want to iterate over the objects multiple times without running the database query each time.

Comment: No. It is cached into the instance so after you run the first loop the second one won't execute the query but use the data from the first. In fact, that is not specific to `select_related()` but all querysets. You DO NOT need to put it into a list to have it cached.

Comment: Yes indeed you are right. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how about using @cached_property for `foo.bars.selected_related('blog')` ?